# Predator missile hack in MW2

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, cheats

I was recently playing a team deathmatch game where I got the predator missile, called it in and when I hit the boost button it instantly exploded.  Instead of exploding on impact, it teleported...like commando predator...:)

How did someone manage to do this?  I was playing on PS3.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were in a hacked lobby, not the lose all your stats hacked lobby hopefully.

[MW 2 hacked on PS3](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/01/17/ps3-hackers-make-modern-warfare-2-unplayable-infinity-ward-ca/)